# How to pass a list as an argument to a function

Tags: python

This is a very fundamental question and I am learning python but I can't seem to find the specific answer to this.

```
class Solution:
def passArray(self, nums: List[int]) -> None:
    """
    practice
    """
    print(nums)
passArray(self, nums:[1,2,3])
```

When I run this code it says "invalid syntax" I am not sure why, How do I pass my list of 123 to this class the right way?

Comment: You don't have indentation and you call `passArray()` from middle of nowhere. Maybe you should look at some basics https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: `nums=[1, 2, 3]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems here.

1. You need to create an object of the class and call the method.
2. You don't need to pass `self` when calling a function/method.
3. To pass arguments, `passArray([1, 2, 3]` or `passArray(nums=[1, 2, 3])`

So ,

```
class Solution:
    def passArray(self, nums: List[int]) -> None:
        """
        practice
        """
        print(nums)
ob = Solution()
ob.passArray([1, 2, 3])
```